# Is there a way to make a list in a list from a table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

This is the code that I have tried:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> select = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> selectin = new ArrayList<String>();
ResultSet lihat = st.executeQuery("select * from usersss");
        while (lihat.next()){
            selectin.set(0, lihat.getString("user"));
            selectin.set(1, lihat.getString("password"));
            selectin.set(2, lihat.getString("email"));
            select.add(selectin);       
        }

for (int i = 0; i<select.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(select.get(i));
        }
```

This is the result:

```
[kursi, meja, kursi@gmail.com]
[kursi, meja, kursi@gmail.com]
[kursi, meja, kursi@gmail.com]
[kursi, meja, kursi@gmail.com]
```

This is the desired result (the actual table):

```
[paosp,skajs,paosp@gmail.com]
[fisd,mole,fisd@gmail.com]
[trem,olo,trem@gmail.com]
[kursi,meja,kursi@gmail.com]
```

It seems like the `selectin` list updates itself inside the `select` list. Is there a way to make it not do this?

Comment: put the following statement ArrayList<String> selectin = new ArrayList<String>();
 inside the while loop. Since you are using same arraylist, it is getting overwritten by newer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually replacing the values in same reference of `selectin` variable. And `select` variable only contains the single reference `selectin` multiple times.

Create a new ArrayList for every new element in `select`, like this:

```java
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> select = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ResultSet lihat = st.executeQuery("select * from usersss");

while (lihat.next()){
    ArrayList<String> selectin = new ArrayList<String>();
    selectin.add(lihat.getString("user"));
    selectin.add(lihat.getString("password"));
    selectin.add(lihat.getString("email"));
    select.add(selectin);       
}

for (int i = 0; i<select.size();i++) {
    System.out.println(select.get(i));
}
```

This will create a new object of ArrayList and everytime while loop runs.

And you'll get your expected result.

Answer (score 2):

I think your while loop should be

```
    while (lihat.next() ) {
        selectin = new ArrayList<>();
        selectin.add( lihat.getString("user") );
        selectin.add( lihat.getString("password") );
        selectin.add( lihat.getString("email") );
        select.add( selectin );       
    }
```

Since it is pass by reference, second iteration updates the firstly added arraylist. That is why the output is same after all iterations.

Answer (score 1):

The `set()` method of `java.util.ArrayList` class is used to replace the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.

boolean `add(Object o)`: This method is used to append a specificd element to the end of a list.

you should replace the `set()` with `add()` in the loop.

```
while (lihat.next() ) {
        selectin = new ArrayList<>();
        selectin.add( lihat.getString("user") );
        selectin.add( lihat.getString("password") );
        selectin.add( lihat.getString("email") );
        select.add( selectin );       
    }
```